# how to combine data in two columns, but if any of either column cell is empty, it returns no value

Tags: google-sheets

I want to merge TWO columns of data (join or concatenate). The issue I'm running into is that I need it to return an empty cell. If either one of the cells or let's say the 2nd column does not have any data it should return nothing.

Here is an image

[image]

I have used both concatenate & join text functions. I have looked online for a solution as well but didn't stumble upon what I was looking for. I am fairly new to google spreadsheet so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(OR(A2="",B2=""),"",CONCAT(A2,B2))` past this formula in C2 cell and drag it

Comment: If you need the concatenated string to include a space, you can write it this way (& = Concatenation operator):=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",A1&" "&A2)

Answer (score 0):

use in row 1:

```
=INDEX(IF((A:A="")+(B:B="");;A:A&" "&B:B))
```